# Python 3 backward compatability (shlex.quote vs pipes.quote)

Tags: python, compatibility, shlex

One of my projects uses `shlex.quote` which is available since *python 3.3*. But that `shlex.quote` is the same as `pipes.quote` which is deprecated after moving to shlex.

Now for compatibility I am using this code:

```
def cmd_quote(string):
    import sys
    if int(sys.version[2]) < 3:
        import pipes
        return pipes.quote(string)
    else:
        import shlex
        return shlex.quote(string)
```

Are any better practices exists?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, if you want to do numerical comparisons against version, use [`version_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info), don't try to parse the string in `version`.*

This also means you can take advantage of the way tuples are compared and write code like:

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 3):
```

… and it won't break if Python gets to 3.10.0 or 4.0 ever come out.

<sub>* Unless you need to worry about 1.5 vs. 2.0, in which case you've obviously got a time-machine gatewaying between Usenet and StackOverflow, and surely you can think of better uses for that.</sub>

---

Anyway, it's probably better to just test for `shlex.quote` existing in the first place. That way, it's obvious to the reader what you're doing: using `shlex.quote` if possible, falling back to `pipes.quote` if not.

You'll see that pattern all over the place—even in the stdlib, where code is imported from C accelerator modules if possible, but fallback code is used if not (e.g., if you're using PyPy instead of CPython).

---

Also, note that `pipes.quote` is *only* documented in 2.7. Not 3.0-3.2 (which is what it seems like you care about…), or 2.6, or any other version. You're relying on something that happens to be there in a particular implementation. (Well, practically, in all of them,* but still, why rely on that if you don't have to?)

<sub>* As far as I know, there aren't any 3.2 implementations that have `pipes` and `shlex` but don't have `pipes.quote`. And there probably won't be too many new 3.2 implementations created in the future.</sub>

---

Also, while it can occasionally be useful to `import` in the middle of a function, it's kind of a weird thing to do. If there's a problem with the installation on a machine you deploy this on, would you really expect to be able to import your module successfully, but then later get an `ImportError` on calling some function? That's the kind of thing people get baffled by and run to SO for help with all the time. :) (It's also obviously a bit of a performance hit to do all this looking in `sys.modules` and converting strings to ints and so on when you don't need to, but I doubt that's going to matter.)

---

So, I think the way I'd write it would be:

```
try:
    from shlex import quote as cmd_quote
except ImportError:
    from pipes import quote as cmd_quote
```